# Change href based on URI using PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement, uri

I'm trying to make a main menu bar link dynamic, based on the visitor's current page.

I started with

```
 $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Which, of course, returns things like

- /subfolder/page.html
- /subfolder1/subfolder2/page.html
- /page.html

I need to grab whatever is after the first '/'. I've tried messing around with explode, but I stumble with what to do with the resulting array. I'm also going cross-eyed trying to write a regex - seems a more elegant solution.

Then I need to build my switch. Something along the lines of:

```
switch ($path)
{
case '/subfolder0':
  $link = $root_url.'/subfolder0/anotherfolder/page.html';
  break;
case '/subfolder1':
  $link = $root_url.'/subfolder1/page.html';
  break;
default:
  $link = $root_url.'/subfolder2/page.html';
}
```

Finally, should I be using if...elseif for this in lieu of switch?

Thanks for your time, all!

Comment: Did you mean "...whatever is after the first '/' [AND before the second '/']..." ?

Comment: In some cases, there will not be a second '/'.

Answer (score 2):

To grab everything after the first /:

```
strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
```

Or, with regex:

```
preg_match('#(/.*)#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);  // $matches[1] will be the path
```

As far as the switch, I'd say if/elseif/else is the least-elegant in your case, switch isn't bad, but personally I'd go with an associative array:

```
$mapping = array('/subfolder0' => $root_url.'/subfolder0/anotherfolder/page.html', 'etc' => 'etc');
$link = $mapping($path);
```

This lets you keep the mapping in another file for organization, and makes it a little bit easier to maintain by separating configuration from implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Using explode is not at all a bad idea if you are interested in all the parts of the URI, you should take a look at the [documentation for explode](http://php.net/explode)

Its usage would be like so:

```
$exploded = explode('/','/path/to/page.html');

echo $exploded[0]; // Will print out '' (empty string)
echo $exploded[1]; // Will print out 'path'
echo $exploded[2]; // Will print out 'to'
echo $exploded[3]; // Will print out 'page.html'
```

However as far as I understand, you are looking to replace the link by whatever is after the first character (which is always '/'), you could use substr like so:

```
// Get whatever is after the first character and put it into $path
$path = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
```

In your case, it is not needed because you are able to predict there is a backslash at the beginning of the string.

I would also suggest using an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to replace the URL.

I would implement the entire thing like so (removing the first backslash as you require):

```
// Define the URLs for replacement
$urls = array(
    'subfolder0' => '/subfolder0/anotherfolder/page.html',
    'subfolder1' => '/subfolder1/page.html'
);

// Get the request URI, trimming its first character (always '/')
$path = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);

// Set the link according to $urls associative array, or set
// the default URL if not found
$link = $urls[$path] or '/subfolder2/page.html';
```

Or with explode, taking only the first part of the URI:

```
// Get the parts of the request
$requestParts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Set the link according to $urls associative array, or set
// the default URL if not found
$link = $urls[$requestParts[1]] or '/subfolder2/page.html';
```

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing the OP's question, I think he/she meant to phrase it as "Everything after the first '/', but before the second '/'. Here is what I got:

You could try this regex:

```
<?php

/*
 *  Regex: /((\w+?|\w+\.\w+?)(?!^\/))(?=\/.*$|$)/
 */

$paths = array(
    '/subfolder9/',
    '/subfolder/page.html',
    '/subfolder1/subfolder2/page.html',
    '/page.html'
);

foreach ($paths as $path) {
    preg_match("/((\w+?|\w+\.\w+?)(?!^\/))(?=\/.*$|$)/", $path, $matches);
    debug($matches);
}

// $matches[1] will contain the first group ( ) matched in the expression.
// or "subfolder<#>" or "<page>.<ext>"

// The loop results is as follows:
Array
(
    [0] => subfolder9
    [1] => subfolder9
    [2] => subfolder9
)

Array
(
    [0] => subfolder
    [1] => subfolder
    [2] => subfolder
)

Array
(
    [0] => subfolder1
    [1] => subfolder1
    [2] => subfolder1
)

Array
(
    [0] => page.html
    [1] => page.html
    [2] => page.html
)

?>
```

Note: This only works with regex flavors that support look-arounds (zero-width positive & negative look ahead are the ones used the example.)

This a great cheat sheet for regular expressions and I don't code without it.

[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - (click to view)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function to get what you want:

```
$path = dirname('/subfolder/page.html'); // returns '/subfolder'
$path = dirname('/subfolder1/subfolder2/page.html'); // returns '/subfolder1'
$path = dirname('page.html'); // returns '.'
```

**EDIT:** Regex based solution:

```
$path = preg_replace('#^(/[^/]*).*$#', '$1', '/subfolder/page.html' )
```

Comment: What if the file is assumed and the URI ends up being: "/subfolder/" ?

That would return "/". The regex I provided handles both cases.

Comment: @Drewdiddy611: Thanks for pointing out, added an edit section for better handling of these edge cases.